# How to change method in controller when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my site I have cards, cards that need to pop up when a button "usa" is clicked and cards that need to appear when a button "europe" is clicked. I coded everything except the last part. If I enter this in my index method of the controller only usa card come up:

```
def index
  @foods = Food.usa
end
```

And if I enter this:

```
def index
  @foods = Food.europe
end
```

only europe cards pop up. I want to be able to do that with a simple button click on my site. how do I do that?

The code of my buttons

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="europe" autocomplete="off" checked> Europe
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="usa" autocomplete="off"> USA
  </label>
</div>
```

The name of my controller is foods_controller.rb

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What does your current button code look like? What have you considered trying? Have have you actually tried?

Comment: I thought using 2 radio buttons.

Comment: Sounds promising. Give it a go and let us know how it turns out.

Comment: <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Europe
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> USA
      </label>
    </div> This is the button group I would like to use

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to put code in comments. Edit your question to include code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a param to your controller with the value of your radio button which will be `usa` or `europe`

Then you can use `send` method to dynamically call `usa` or `europe` on your `Food` model.

For instance, you sent a parameter `food_name` from frontend to your controller.

Your code will look something like this

```
def index
  @foods = Food.send(params[:food_type].to_sym)
end
```

But be careful when directly using params coming from user as it may break your application.

A **safe approach** will be to create a array of possible food types in your controller.

Something like this:

```
SUPPORTED_FOOD_TYPES = ["usa", "europe"].freeze
```

Then in your controller you'd do it like this

```
def index
  @foods = Food.send(food_type.to_sym)
end


def food_type
  if SUPPORTED_FOOD_TYPES.include? params[:food_type]
    params[:food_type]
  else
    'all'
  end
end
```

Your html code will look like this:

```
<%= form_tag(foods_path, method: "get") do %>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="food_type" value="europe" id="europe" autocomplete="off" checked> Europe
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="food_type" value="usa" id="usa" autocomplete="off"> USA
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Apply">
<% end %>
```

Comment: So how do i define food_type in in my button group?

Comment: My html code is in the index page itself from food. This doesn't work.

Comment: So how are you showing cards on button click? Have you implemented this?

Comment: No that's the major problem.

Comment: This is my github if you need more code https://github.com/Maartensdb/lvlytoulouse .

Comment: I have the error undefined local variable or method `food_type' for #. Where do I need to define food_type?

Comment: Have you added the both methods in controller?

Comment: If I add the food_type method I get this error: uninitialized constant FoodsController::SUPPORTED_FOOD_TYPES .

Comment: You also need to define the `SUPPORTED_FOOD_TYPES` constant on your controller. I've mentioned it in my answer

Comment: Now I get this: undefined method `to_sym' for false:FalseClass Did you mean? to_s

Comment: Updated the `food_type` method, use the newer version

Comment: No errors now but my button group doesn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to pass the food model scope as a query param so something like this in your controller:

```
def index
  if params[:food_type].present?
    @foods = Food.send(params[:food_type].to_sym)
  else
    @foods = Food.all # fallback to something or all?
  end
end
```

Without seeing the rest of your font end code, there are a number of ways to handle it.  Most likely you will load the view without data and then send an ajax request with the `food_type` as a param when the button is clicked.